# Error in servlet-context.xml

Tags: servlets, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

I have the following as my servlet-context.xml in STS, which produces an error `Build path is Incomplete. Cannot find class file for javax/servlet.ServletContext`. If I comment the line `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>`, the error disappears. But I clearly want to enable Transactional behaviour, hence I need to keep it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd"
>

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.bilitutor.cct" />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <!-- STS shows ERROR : Build path is Incomplete. Cannot find class file for javax/servlet.ServletContext -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Create a Session Factory -->
    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/cct" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="initialSize" value="2" />
        <beans:property name="maxActive" value="5" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.bilitutor.cct" />
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <!-- Prepare the User DAO -->
    <beans:bean id="UserDAO" class="com.bilitutor.cct.dao.UserDAOImpl" >
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Register @Autowired annotation -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <!-- Enable Transaction -->
    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <!-- COMMENTING THE FOLLOWING LINE MAKES THE ERROR DISAPPEAR -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>    

</beans:beans>
```

Also, my pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.bilitutor.cct</groupId>
    <artifactId>BiliTutor</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Used for Hibernate4 LocalSessionFactoryBean -->
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AOP dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Persistence Management -->
        <!-- Apache BasicDataSource -->
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL database driver -->
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this should solve your problem:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Or, if you are using servlet 3.1 (or 3.0.1), you can use something like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```